# Multiply Woocommerce deposit value if radio button is selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have built a Woocommerce solution for a school. They have a complex variety of options for each course, so used some plugins to help accomplish their goals.

For each course, you have the option to select the duration (`2 weeks` or `4 weeks`), among some other options, so you have some radio buttons to select them. These are managed by a plugin.

You also have to choose if you want to pay the full price right on or pay a deposit value. This is managed by another plugin (Woothemes Deposits).

[image: Here is a screenshot of the product options]

Woothemes Deposits only offer the option to set a single fixed price for deposits, and that's it. But the deposit value set by the school is two times the value for the `4 weeks` duration option.

So my goal is to multiply the deposit value by 2 if the 4 weeks radio button is selected.

I looked into the Woothemes Deposits files and found this function, which supposedly manages the add to cart event:

```
public function add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['is_deposit'] ) ) {

        $deposit_amount = WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::get_deposit_amount( $cart_item['data'], ! empty( $cart_item['payment_plan'] ) ? $cart_item['payment_plan'] : 0 );

        if ( false !== $deposit_amount ) {

            $cart_item['deposit_amount'] = $deposit_amount;

            // [...] other stuff that doesn't matter here

            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['deposit_amount'] );

        }
    }

    return $cart_item;
}
```

So I tried to add this before `return $cart_item;`:

```
if ( $_POST['tmcp_radio_0'] == "4 weeks_1") {
      $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['price'] * 2 );
    }
```

`tmcp_radio_0` is the radio buttons name and `4 weeks_1` is the value of the target radio button...

But no success. I tried adding variations of this on some other lines of this function, sometimes I get all deposits (even the 2 weeks ones) multiplied by 2, sometimes I get a 500 error.

Any light? Am I trying to do it on the right place? I know that I'm not supposed to modify plugin files but I'm just trying to understand what is happening and then try to come up with a more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I have this plugin, but if you go to the `WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::get_deposit_amount()` method, is there a filter you could use to adjust the deposit?

Comment: Well, I looked through this `get_deposit_amount()` function and found that at the end of it it returns a `$price` variable. I tried to modify it using that if statement:

`if ( $_POST['tmcp_radio_0'] == "4 weeks_1" ) {
   $multiplier = 2;
  } else {$multiplier = 1; }

  $price = $price * $multiplier;

  return wc_format_decimal( $price );`

But it didn't work. The deposit price remained the same (I guess it just got multiplied by 1, even when I selected the `4 weeks_1` radio button before submitting the form).